# How to tell the url has a # query string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a script in JS to tell if the URL has the # st like `https://hoogabooga/t/wow.html#btn1`
so I can have it can change the background color of that element.

Because I'm making the pages non-scrollable and small I need to make making pages that extended part of each type of content... (If more was supposed to be there) and making buttons to go to the content on the new page that is that of finish what was left off, and the way I know how to do that is to send them to a page `wow.html` with the `#btn1` but the page can't scroll.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say I follow. You want to see if the URL has a # (hash) in it? There's the `hashchange` event, or you can check if the # symbol exists with [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to detect a change to the hash:

```
function hashHandler() {
  console.log('The hash has changed to ' + location.hash);
}

window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashHandler, false);
```

if you just want to see what is the current hash: `console.log(location.hash)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hash value from `window.location.hash`.

For example.com/#btn1, `window.location.hash` would contain `btn1`.

It sounds like you're trying to respond to hash changes though, like putting a hash in an anchor's href attribute. For that, you want `window.onhashchange`.

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
    var newHash = window.location.hash;

    if(newHash == "something")
    { 
        //load new page 
    }
}
```

For the record, this can be accomplished just as easily with click events.

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething()">
```